# React Toggle Not Changing Boolean Value

Tags: reactjs, toggle, next.js

I have a simple component using a toggle in Nextjs. I would like to change the content of the button based on whether 'isOpen' is true or false. However, the console shows isOpen is always set to false. Here's the code:

```
export class Hamburger extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isOpen: false }
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
}

toggle() {
    this.setState = ({isOpen: !this.state.isOpen})
    console.log(this.state.isOpen)
}

render() {
    return (
        <button onClick={this.toggle} type="button">
            {this.state.isOpen ? <Component1 /> : <Component2 /> }
        </button>
    )
}
}

export default Hamburger
```

I've researched answers on SE all morning but I still can't understand why isOpen is not changing.

Any help would be very much appreciated!! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If your new state depends on your previous state, call `setState` with a callback like this:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    isOpen: !prevState.isOpen
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your new state update depends on the previous state, always use the functional form of 'setState' which accepts as argument a function that returns a new state.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    check: !prevState.check
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check the default value first
this.setState = ({isOpen: this.state.isOpen ? false : true })